# Are questions about taught graduate programs designed for professionals on topic

Tags: discussion

I personally think that there are three types of graduate programs in the world (with suitable gray areas between them). Traditional taught/research based programs, taught graduate programs designed for industry professionals, and diploma mills. Any question about a diploma mill is off topic in my mind, even if it could theoretically fall under the "life as a graduate student" [category](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). [Industry certifications as program entrance requirements?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/industry-certifications-as-program-entrance-requirements) made me think about if taught graduate programs designed for professionals are on topic. These types of questions, as they are not research based at all, do not fall under the "Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher" [category](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), but they might fall under the "life as" category.

What are peoples thoughts on the scope of AC.SE? Are questions about graduate programs designed for industry professionals on topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graduate-level programs are typically considered on-topic, so long as they would otherwise fit into the theme of the group. (In other words, no questions about *individual* programs.)